# How to stop service worker creating cache?

Tags: reactjs, caching, progressive-web-apps

I made a react web app. I added a service worker to get the PWA app. I just need the PWA app to add it on the home screen and use it on fullscreen view, I don't need any more functionalities like - offline browse, save cache, etc.
Now I am facing a problem, every time I deploy my app, I need to clear the browser cache. Sometimes I have to go to Incognito mode to see the changes.
So, How I will stop this?